# Какое отличие цитаты от прямой речи?

Tags: цитата

Можно ли оформлять с помощью тире, начиная с нового абзаца, чьи-то слова, которые были приведены в каком-то источнике (в газете, на сайте, в книге)?

Например:

— П, — сказал он.

или возможно лишь так:

"П", — сказал он.

Comment: спасибо, что исправили на тире.

Answer (score 2):

Чьи-то слова - это реплика, значит, возможно оформить как реплику в диалоге, с помощью тире с новой строки.